# Android app background thread behavior

Tags: android, multithreading, http-post

I have a basic app that uses a background thread to post values to our server. The code is below. When I run the code, in debugging or normally, the following line throws a NullException (though when debugging, the value of the backgroundThread variable is set). Every subsequent run through works fine. I'm new to Android development and am unsure what is causing this discrepancy. I've included the activity function and the server post function.

```
backgroundThread.start();
```

This line is what throws the NullException. Any ideas on what is causing the problem? Thanks for any help you can provide.

--UPDATE
@jonas452 & @Rudi

I changed the code to use asynctask and am struggling with the return value. postResult is always null, and breakpoints in the postTo function never run it seems. Probably a dumb error but I'm not sure what is amiss.

--UPDATE
I worked out the issue. The AsyncTask was setup correctly, but because it's asynchronous, postResult was not immediately available. I moved my check into the onPostExecute function of the AsyncTask and everything works fine.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    try {
        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            final String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            scan_format.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            scan_content.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
            error.setText(null);
            output.setText(null);
            neonetpost post = new neonetpost();
            post.execute(scanContent);
            /*
            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                    postResult = postTo(scanContent);
                   }
               });
            backgroundThread.start();
            */
            if(postResult.indexOf("ERROR: ")>-1)
                error.setText(postResult);
            else
                output.setText(postResult);
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        error.setText("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}


public class neonetpost extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {  
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return postTo(params[0], params[1]);
    }

    public String postTo(String operation) {
        return postTo(operation, "E:1");
    }
    public String postTo(String operation, String employee)
    {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://domain.com/page.php");

            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operation", operation));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("employee", employee));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do nothing. 
            //So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not an interface
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

            while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }

            postResult = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            postResult =  "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
        } 
        return postResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Java Threads, use the AsyncTask class.
Here is a good tutorial:
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html

Comment: I looked at that and was unsure if I could get the return value of the post page using async. You can see following the post, I need to check the return of the post for confirmation.

Comment: Although true, that doesn't explain his `NullPointerException`.

Comment: jonas452 & @Rudi I updated the post with the asynctask I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

the line that gives you NPE is `if(postResult.indexOf("ERROR: ")>-1)`. You made the assumption that calling

```
backgroundThread.start();
```

made the UI Thread wait, till `backgroundThread` finished its execution and assign a value to `postResult`, but Thread are executed asynchronously. and   `backgroundThread.start();`
makes the system spawn a new thread. When this is executed is up to the scheduler

Comment: When I step through debugging with breakpoints on backgroundThread.start() & if(postResult.indexOf("ERROR: ")>-1), it gets to backgroundThread.start(), and when I resume from there it immediately jumps to the catch exception. It never gets to the breakpoint on the if statement. Because I catch the error, I can run it again and there is no error and I do get to the if statement.

Comment: print the stacktrace (e.printStackTrace(); ) of the exception. It'll point the line and reason of the crash